# Will autocert renew certificate or should you do it yourself

Tags: go

Regarding Letsencrypt and go autocert - I am asking here as I see autocert being a go package( Please direct or correct me.)

Will `golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert` renew certificate automatically, or should you:

1. make a timer,
2. check date
3. Renew(before expire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/70a84ac30bf957c7df57edd1935d2081871515e1/acme/autocert/autocert.go#L132  it seems this'll auto renew based on the duration you specify.